# "How do I change the operating system license from BYOL to PAYG for a Google Compute Engine instance?"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-compute-engine

I migrated a machine from AWS to GCP using the BYOL license, but the client said it should be PAYG. How do I change the license from BYOL to PAYG? I managed to add the PAYG license, but when I list the instance licenses, the BYOL license URL is also listed.
Could someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Even though you added the PAYG license, the BYOL license URL might still be listed because it hasn't been explicitly removed but it doesn't necessarily mean the BYOL license is actively used.

Remove the BYOL license using `gcloud`.

```
gcloud compute licenses delete my-byol-license
```

Make sure that you've correctly assigned the PAYG license to the migrated machine.